# Firefox deployment concept: Linux

Tags: linux, firefox, deployment

Context:
30 stations, all clones --- public kiosks; using Firefox. I'd like to be able to use
fabric to deploy firefox + addons + user scripts to the stations that do not have it, or, need an updated version.

Concept:
I already figured out the part about installing Firefox --- so, case closed there. As far as deploying addons and user settings/scripts ---

Couldn't one just sync the user's .mozilla directory in such a way that it preserved permissions? Addons and settings are kept in this directory, I believe. I've tried syncing the entire user directory but ran into what I think was just a permissions issue.

Has anyone done it this way? I don't want to mess with custom deb files. Did you use rsync? cpio/tar to preserve permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox plugins can be placed in `/usr/lib(64)?/mozilla/plugins` for access by all users.

As for user settings, is there a reason you have to replicate it to every kiosk instead of using a networked filesystem for the user home directory?

Comment: yes, network is flaky in some locations. We cover 30 locations across thousands of miles. It is definitely out of the question ...even with slave or duplicate servers serving --- the new overhead is a poor ROI. A simple sync has no to low overhead and easy to troubleshoot w/out extra equipment, hosts ...etc. ** Also, if I put the plugins in that directory will they be installed for every user by default?